# How to call a service by his name at controller runtime in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, service, dependency-injection

I am passing the service name from one controller to another controller as argument in angularjs. When I receive that variable in the second controller and use it as service name then I get an error i.e. serviceNameVariable.get is not a function. So my question is that, How can I use a variable as service name in a controller ?

Comment: Passing things (especially services, that can be injected independently) between controllers sounds like an anti pattern to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: service name means ? , if its service , factory ,value .... you can inject the name by creating the respective service ,

Answer (score 3):

It's not that difficult to get a service by his name.

Dependency injection can also be done at runtime in angular :

```
angular.module("someApp").controller("childController", [
    "$injector",
    function($injector){
        var serviceName = "someServiceName";

        var service = $injector.get(serviceName);

        service.executeAction(someParams);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at Angular's [$injector service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) which allows you to dynamically retrieve your own or native angular modules anywhere:

> `$injector` is used to retrieve object instances as defined by provider, instantiate types, invoke methods, and load modules.

We inject the `$injector` service like any other:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($injector) {
    var serviceNameVariable = '$http'; // or some input
    var service = $injector.get(serviceNameVariable);

    // Use the 'injected' service, in this case the $http#get method:
    service.get('http://endpoint');
});
```